# How can I compute the cardinality of $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Given a finite field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ with associated ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, how can I find the cardinality of the finite field $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i$ where $\mathfrak{p}_i$ lies over $(p)$ and
$$
(p) = \mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}
$$
For example, I want to be able to compute the finite field from
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2 + 1, 2-x)}
$$
where
$$
(5) = (2-i)(2+i)
$$

Comment: A surefire method would be to write both $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ as free abelian groups (they have the same rank $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$). Then use the methods from the theory of finitely generated abelian groups: form the matrix with coordinate vectors of the generators of the ideal w.r.t. the chosen integral basis as rows, and then compute the invariant factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Gaussian integers you could just calculate the norm, $N(2-i)=5$  (Note that $(2+i)(2-i)=5$ not 3!)

Comment: Is there a method in general though for computing the size of the field?

Comment: Section 2.3 of some notes from Franz Lemmermeyer here -> http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ant/ant02.pdf are recommended in several posts.